# img outside div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following:

```
.home-thumbs h2 {
    background: url("images/top-left-label.png") no-repeat scroll left top #CBCBCB;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -66px;
    max-width: 268px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
```

I only want to get that small png with a cut corner outside my div, but can't manage to do it. How should I do it, what am I missing here?!

The div is meant to be a "label" for a title over an image. I am having the same problem with a tooltip from a testimonial, I can't use the bottom part with the arrows and normal borders as, again, my img won't show outside the containing div.

Thanks.

P.S. HTML & PHP ..

```
<div id="home" class="home-thumbs">
  <?php query_posts('cat=19&posts_per_page=1'); 
  if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <p class="cat-title"><?php echo single_cat_title();?></p> <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php $cat_id = 19; $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat_id ); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $cat_link; ?>">More in this section</a>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML in question. As asked, there is no div, img, or any other HTML, which makes it impossible to tell what the CSS is meant to be doing.

Comment: Done it. But really, for such a simple thing, where is obvious that is a h2 and I did mention that is supposed to stay in top/outside my image.. I thought it's pointless to point the html.

Answer (score 1):

You have it positioned absolutely, so use `top` and `left` as you're supposed to

```
.home-thumbs h2 {
    background: url("images/top-left-label.png") no-repeat scroll left top #CBCBCB;
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 268px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -66px;
    left: -8px;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to move the bg not the h2 itself. So your solution doesn't help me at all, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow:visible` on the containing `<div>`.